# Why the Vaadin CONNECT_JAVA_SOURCE_FOLDER_TOKEN property doesn't work

Tags: vaadin-flow

The property vaadin.javaSourceFolder is deleted from the Vaadin BuildFrontendUtil.java at runtime like [shown in line 471](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/7276d67b403ff85c0e7ba931fa3606bb06ae8d7c/flow-plugins/flow-plugin-base/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/plugin/base/BuildFrontendUtil.java)

Does anybody know how to define this property in order to change the `javaSourceFolder`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define this in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
             <configuration>
              <javaSourceFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/example</javaSourceFolder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```